# Converting an application using Keith Palmer's QBWC framework to QuickBooks Online

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We're using [Keith Palmer/Consolibyte Solutions' excellent PHP QuickBooks Framework](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks) in our web application to communicate with QuickBooks Desktop edition via the QuickBooks Web Connector. We're using a `QuickBooks_Server` and a `QuickBooks_Queue` in our code as follows:

```
$this->myQBQueue = new QuickBooks_Queue($this->myDSN);

$mappedFunctions = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER,
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER,
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT,
    QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER,
);

$map = array();

foreach($mappedFunctions as $function) {
    $map[$function] = array(
        array($this,"quickbooks{$function}Request"),
        array($this,"quickbooks{$function}Response"),
    );
}

$errmap = array('*' => array($this,'quickbooksErrorHandler'));

$hooks = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_HANDLERS_HOOK_LOGINFAILURE => array(
        array($this,'quickbooksLoginFailureHook')
    ),
    QUICKBOOKS_HANDLERS_HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => array(
        array($this,'quickbooksLoginSuccessHook')
    )
);

$soap_options = array();
$handler_options = array();
$driver_options = array();
$callback_options = array();

$this->myQBServer = new QuickBooks_Server($this->myDSN, $map, $errmap, $hooks, QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, QUICKBOOKS_SOAPCLIENT_BUILTIN, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
```

We now have a customer who has requested that we add support for QuickBooks online. Can we still use a `QuickBooks_Server` and a `QuickBooks_Queue` using Keith Palmer's framework for QuickBooks online, or do we have to write new code for the QuickBooks online portion?

Comment: Are you building a SaaS application (e.g. allowing your customers to connect their QuickBooks files to your app, and charging them on a recurring basis for your service) or is this an internal/one-off/custom integration for just your company?

Comment: @KeithPalmer it is a SaaS application but it doesn't have a monthly fee -- just a setup fee. It's an add-on to our eCommerce system. I have seen your other answers suggesting IPP is better than qbXML but since we already have an entire qbXML/WebConnector app built and IPP carries a monthly fee, I think switching to IPPwould be more difficult...

Answer (score 2):

You *could* re-use the Queue stuff, but the framework doesn't natively support it - you could definitely hack it in easily though.

You will also *definitely* be able to re-use most (but not all) of your qbXML.

QuickBooks Online does support a qbXML interface (though it's not terribly good - Intuit has publicly stated that they will likely deprecate it within the next year or so, and they are no longer adding features to it). You should know that *in the near future*, it's *very likely* that you'll want to start thinking about moving towards Intuit Anywhere/IDS - **especially** if you're a SaaS app with a lot of QuickBooks Online customers.

You can find the qbXML docs for QuickBooks Online here:
http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html
  (make sure you tick the "OE" checkbox and uncheck the "US" checkbox)

A few things that bite a lot of people with QuickBooks Online:

- When adding Payments, you MUST apply them to an invoice. There is no IsAutoApply in QBO
- There's no support for UPDATING invoices in the qbXML API for QBO
- There's no support for inventory items in the qbXML API for QBO

If you look at the docs/example_online_edition.php (or docs/example_raw_online_edition.php) file included with the QuickBooks PHP DevKit library code you have, you'll see how it works. Basically instead of a queue, you're just sending straight qbXML requests to Intuit's server via HTTPS instead of wrapping it in SOAP and waiting for the Web Connector to pick it up.

With that said, if you really wanted to continue using the Queue, you could - Queue stuff up just as you normally do, and just set up a script something like this that runs on a cron job:

(WARNING - totally untested code, you'll have to test and debug)

```
<?php

// Do some setup stuff here as shown in the example... 

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quickbooks_queue WHERE qb_username = 'the username' AND qb_status = 'q'");
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  $request_function = $map[$arr['qb_action']][0];
  $response_function = $map[$arr['qb_action']][1];

  $requestID = null;   // not relevant for QBO
  $user = 'the username';
  $ID = $arr['ident']; 
  $extra = null;
  if($arr['extra']) $extra = unserialize($arr['extra']);
  $err = null;
  $last_action_time = null;
  $last_actionident_time = null;
  $version = '6.0'; // QBO only supports 6.0
  $locale = 'US';   // QBO only supports US
  $qbxml = $request_function($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale);

  $xml = $API->qbxml($qbxml);

  $idents = _extractIdentifiers($xml);   // You can find this function in QuickBooks/Handlers.php and pull it into your app as a function instead of a method

  $response_function($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, $err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents);
}
```